# Markdown syntax isn't applied to my GitHub blog's post

Tags: github, markdown

[image]

As you can see, Markdown syntax isn't applied to my blog.

[image]

This is my GitHub

[image]

I am using the 'minimal-mistake' theme.

One expectation is that in the process of applying the 'minimal-mistakes' theme to my blog, I didn't clone all the files in the theme, but added only the parts I needed.

Could this be a problem?

Comment: Please read [ask]. In general, please always include _source code_ when asking questions here. There's very little we can do based on screenshots of the rendered result, though in this case I think I know the problem (see below).

Comment: I apologize aoubt my question

Comment: No need to apologize. We all make mistakes. In this case I think I was able to provide an answer based on your screenshots. Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Put a space after any hashes you are using for a headline.

Instead of

```
###Title
```

write

```
### Title
```

This has a secondary benefit of being considerably more readable in its source form, which [was a design goal for Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

> The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions.